# Pipe answer from tasklist to check mem usage of process and kill if exceeding threshold

Tags: powershell, tasklist

I found a powershell version that does the job but it uses WMI and thats the process i have issue with, its leaking and hits the 512MB roof and stops working "out of memory".

> $processToMonitor = 'wmiprvse.exe'
> $threshold = 513MB
>
> Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='$processToMonitor' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize > $threshold" -Action { Get-Process -PID $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.ProcessId | Stop-Process -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null }

So the above will not work when WMI is out of memory, so could i use some other way of doing the same thing?

If i use:

> tasklist | find "WmiPrvSE.exe"

It spits out the current WmiPrvSE processes with pid, and memory usage. And ideas of how i can use that?

There is a patch for this WMI leak issue but i cant patch all servers as soon as i want.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$task = (tasklist | select-string 'Wmiprvse.exe') -split '\s+'

$proc = $task[0] -replace '\.exe'
[int]$mem = $task[-2] -replace '\.'

if ($mem -gt (513MB /1KB) )
{
  (get-process $proc).kill()
}
```

but this is equivalent and preferable ( two session of wmiprvse.exe can exist!):

```
Get-Process wmiprvse | ? { $_.ws -gt 513MB } | Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: Dang, I was 2 seconds from posting the edit you just made using get-process! That would be my route as well

Comment: Oki doki, thx for the code. I tried the later one and that kills the WMI process that only was 4MB so i don't know if the 513MB flag did not work. I will try the first code snipp tomorrow also. :)

Comment: I just ran method 1 and it i guess it uses WMI to ask the question, i got this response: "ERROR: Out of memory"

Comment: So i tried the second one again now and it looks like it does the job great. Tnx :)